# Android TextRecognizer TextBlocks out of order when 4 or more are detected

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I have been using **Google Vision api** *to scan Images for text and display them in a TextView*, the only problem is if it detects 4 or more TextBlocks within the image the blocks appear out of order. I have been looking for a solution to the problem but haven't found one so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for translating the image:

```
   public void RunOCR(TextView scanResults, Context context) {
    detector = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build();
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pic.jpg"));
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(context, imageUri);
            if (detector.isOperational() && bitmap != null) {
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = detector.detect(frame);
                String blocks = "";
                String lines = "";
                String words = "";
                int number = 0;
                boolean goneThroughLoop = false;
                //if(textBlocks.size() >= 4){number = textBlocks.size() - 2;}
                for (int index = number; index < textBlocks.size(); index++) {
                    //extract scanned text blocks here
                    if(index == textBlocks.size() - 2 && goneThroughLoop){break;}
                    TextBlock tBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(index);
                    blocks = blocks + tBlock.getValue() + "\n" + "\n";
                    for (Text line : tBlock.getComponents()) {
                        //extract scanned text lines here
                        lines = lines + line.getValue() + "\n";
                        for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text words here
                            words = words + element.getValue() + ", ";
                        }
                    }
                    /*if(index == textBlocks.size() - 1 && !goneThroughLoop){index = 0; goneThroughLoop = true; ;
                        tBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(index);
                        blocks = blocks + tBlock.getValue() + "\n" + "\n";
                        for (Text line : tBlock.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text lines here
                            lines = lines + line.getValue() + "\n";
                            for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                                //extract scanned text words here
                                words = words + element.getValue() + ", ";
                            }
                        }*/

                    }
                }
                if (textBlocks.size() == 0) {
                    scanResults.setText("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan");
                } else {
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + blocks + "\n");
                }
            } else {
                scanResults.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

edit: The recent fix of using if statements(commented out in code) to rearrange the blocks no longer works. Links below are screenshots of the problem I've been having.

[Scanned image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_I_5fURAbCgNGhQLTIxY3NfWlE/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Resulting text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_I_5fURAbCgSFFLbXc3MFJZNU0/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Try this https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Comment: It's giving word by word